# How to test GraphQL Error as a BFF using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, graphql

**Below code is to test that function has error and extensions is present in the error as { response : { status: 500 } }**
*However it gives error in test case, I can get the Error consoled in the catch block.*

```
 GraphQLError: api failed

  70 |         const error = new GraphQLError(message, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, extensions);
  71 |         jest.spyOn(RESTDataSource.prototype as any, 'get').mockImplementation(async () => {
> 72 |             throw new GraphQLError(message, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, extensions);
     |                   ^
  73 |         });
  74 |         expect(await api.getCustDetail(mockToken, mockId, mockCoId)).rejects.toThrow(error);
  75 |     });

it.only('test getCustDetail with unsuccessful response', async () => {
    const message = 'api failed';
    const extensions = { response: { status: 500 } };
    const error = new GraphQLError(message, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, extensions);
    jest.spyOn(RESTDataSource.prototype as any, 'get').mockImplementation(async () => {
        throw error;
    });
    expect(await api.getCustDetail(mockToken, mockId, mockCoId)).rejects.toThrow(error);
});
```

Comment: You have `await` in the wrong place. To use `.rejects` successfully you need to pass a _promise_ to `expect`.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, As my function is an async await function. 
If I try to check the Type of Error as 
`const errorResonse = await api.getCustDetail(mockToken, mockId, mockCoId);
expect(errorResponse).toThrow(GraphQLError);`

It still fails. 
This is my catch block...
`catch (error) {
            log.error(   
                {
                    type: 'response',
                   status: error.extensions.response.status
                }
            );
                        throw error;
        }`

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect any different. Again you won't actually reach the assertion because awaiting a rejected promise throws an error. Read https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous and think about how promises work.